# VB Read Line from File starting with "XY" and ignore the XY

Tags: vb.net

Im currently working on a program which basicly writes a number of Files and  their paths into a file & a new path to be used by another computer to put these files on its hard drive.
I don't know how to read the file properly by the second computer. (The "Receiving part" of the program)

The File which should be read looks like this:

```
OTHER STUFF
MORE STUFF
EVEN MORE STUFF  
File1:~\\bar\foo.txt
Path1:~C:\foo
File2:~\\bar\foobar.txt
Path2:~C:\foobar
OTHER STUFF
MORE STUFF
EVEN MORE STUFF
```

How Can I read this file and only get the files and paths and exclude the "File" and "Path"?

I'm sorry if my english is not perfect, please ask if something it's not clear.
I hope you can help me.

Regards

This is what i got so far, but it will only display one character after the ~ (I use that as a seperator now)

```
Dim settings_file As String = "//test/test.txt"
Dim stream_reader As New StreamReader(settings_file)
Dim line As String
line = stream_reader.ReadLine()
Do While Not (line Is Nothing)
    If line.StartsWith("File") Then
        Dim parts As String() = line.Split("~")
        For Each part In parts
            MsgBox(part(1))
        Next
    End If
    line = stream_reader.ReadLine()
Loop
stream_reader.Close()
```

Comment: Do you want the output to be like: http://pastebin.com/raw/nq6zzX58

Comment: No it should be like http://pastebin.com/n3nNSEfu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim lines = File.ReadLines("test\test.txt")

Dim paths = From line In lines
            Where line Like "File#:~*" OrElse line Like "Path#:~*"
            Select Split(line, ":~", 2).Last

Dim result = paths.ToArray
```

or

```
Dim lines = File.ReadLines("test\test.txt")

Dim lookup = lines.ToLookup(Function(l) If(Len(l) < 4, l, Mid(l, 1, 4)), Function(l) Split(l, ":~", 2).Last)

Dim files = lookup("File").ToArray
Dim paths = lookup("Path").ToArray
```

The `.ToLookup` extension will group the items by the first function, and the second function is to select the items that are stored in each group. So, if you loop through `lookup` the keys and items will look like this

```
"OTHE"
    "OTHER STUFF"
    "OTHER STUFF"
"MORE"
    "MORE STUFF"
    "MORE STUFF"
"EVEN"
    "EVEN MORE STUFF  "
    "EVEN MORE STUFF"
"File"
    "\\bar\foo.txt"
    "\\bar\foobar.txt"
"Path"
    "C:\foo"
    "C:\foobar"
```

Comment: Thank you, this works exactly as needed. ( I just need to put Files and path in to different Array to read them out more easily)

Comment: @Alex you can try the alternative if all lines have more than 4 characters.

Comment: Wow that is interesting, why does it have to be 4 characters btw? If u mind explaining me what exactly you have done there with the Loopkup function. regards

Comment: It doesn't have to, but will look more complicated if it has to handle less than 4 characters (see edit).

Comment: I see, can you please post the code before the edit again?I get an System.ArgumentException, the Argument Start has to be bigger than 0. I cant seem to get it back together. It wont have to deal with less than 4 characters though. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I fixed it. You can see the previous versions by clicking on the "edited * ago" link

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I found the solution to the execption, Dim lookup = lines.ToLookup(Function(l) If(Len(l) < 4, l, Mid(l, 1, 4)), Function(l) Split(l, ":~", 2).Last) . This work perfect. thank you

Comment: One more thing, Is there a way ( If I only expect one line with this beginning) to directly get the lookup result as a string? If I try to do "TextBox1.Text = lookup("test").ToString"  i get this: System.Linq.Lookup`2+Grouping[System.String,System.String] or do i just have to do it with an array anyways?

Comment: it has 0 (if not found) or more items, so you can get the first item like this `lookup("test").FirstOrDefault` or join all items with `Join(lookup("test").ToArray, ",")`

Answer (score 1):

It gets easier if you split your problem into smaller parts:

1. Read the file (`File.ReadAllLines`).
2. Iterate through the lines (`For Each`).
3. For each line, check if it starts with the prefix you are looking for (`String.StartsWith`).
4. If it does, split the line on the space (`String.Split`) and retrieve only the second part (`(1)`).

The implementation is left as an exercise; the .NET library method names should be enough to get you started. Feel free to return and ask a more specific question if you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm stuck with the String.Split expression and I'm not sure how to get it to work and how to just get the second part. I'm completly new to VB.

Comment: I got it to work but I can only get it to give me the first character after the delsim.

Comment: @Alex: Instead of the For Each loop, simply use `parts(1)`.